# comma delimited vs list in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a nested type with array property,

```
class MyType
{
  public string Name{ get; set; }
  public List<OtherType> Others { get; set; }
}

class OtherType
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public List<string> Tags { get; set; } // vs what follows
  // public string Tags { get; set; } // eg. = "tag1, tag2, etc"
}
```

what would normally be the best way to go ( list vs comma separated tags)? which will allow me for easier search?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for nested object with property "include_in_parent" true so that you can use normal queries as well as co-related queries on nest object efficiently.

```
{   "MyType": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "OtherType": {
        "type": "nested",
        "include_in_parent": true,
        "properties": {
          "Title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Tags": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }   } }
```